# Resizing image to fit various screens

Tags: css

I am having real problems getting this to work for my site in Firefox, although it works perfectly in IE. I want the contents to resize depending omn the viewport. I have set up all dimensions as % and mostly it is OK, apart from single images.I have read endless posts about it, have tried all the non Java script ones and cannot fix it. I have now created a very small page with nothing else in it apart from a single image for testing purposes. Works fine in IE, but not in Firefox.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<body>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fart.css" TYPE="text/css" />
<title>resize</title>
</head>
<p><img src="george.JPEG" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
image{
width: 30%;
height: 30%;
max-height: 30%
max-width: 30%;
border:2px solid cyan;
}
```

Firefox appears to ignore the CSS for the image and it remains resolutely unchanged when changing the CSS parameters. No resizing and no cyan border. I have also tried various combinations of only using "max", not using "max" and using both "max-height" and "height".
I have also tested it on another PC, just in case Firefox's "about:config" had become messed up on this PC.

I'm an amateur, so please be gentle with me but it's so frustrating to have everything working in one browser but not in the other.
Thanks in advance for anyone that can help.

Carlos

//edit//

I might have fluked upon a reason while messing around. It looks like Firefox requires the CSS tag "img", while IE accepts both. Does that make any sense to anyone?

So

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
image {border:2px solid cyan;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><image src="george.JPEG" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Does not work in Firefox, but does in IE, but

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img {border:2px solid cyan;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><image src="george.JPEG" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

works in both.

Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the IMAGE instead of IMG as your css selector in your css snippet.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%
  max-width: 100%;
  border:2px solid cyan;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle that sizes well: http://jsfiddle.net/7UZ9a/

Getting "auto stretching" of images to work cross browser is pretty tricky. I would fall back to a library that does the heavy lifting for you. I often use backstretch to do this. I use it for http://www.hsvbonus.de for instance. You can download the jquery lib here https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch

Comment: Gotcha koenp. Shows what an amateur I am!